# Why is preact not getting recognized in the terminal even after installing it?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, preact, preact-cli

I have installed Preact but it’s not getting recognized in the terminal. First, I went to the official website of [PreactJS](https://preactjs.com/). The doc says that I have to run `npm install -g preact-cli`. As I am using Yarn, I ran `yarn global add preact-cli`. It was installed successfully but with a lot of warnings. Then I ran `preact create default first-preact-app`. But it's showing an error that "The term 'Preact' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file or executable program."

I have tried force cleaning the cache and reinstalling `preact-cli`. But it doesn't work. Two of the warnings are that `preact` and `preact-render-to-string` have unmet peer dependency. So, I have installed them also. But it still doesn't work.

I have tried running npm and experimented with the commands also. But it didn't work. So, how can I fix the problem?

I have run these commands using Powershell and Git bash on Windows 10. I am trying to install Preact 10.5.12 using Yarn 1.22.5. And a point to be noted, I tried running `yarn dlx` but it returns an error that "command not found". And when the installation of preact and preact-render-to-string gets finished, yarn gives and warning that they have no binaries.

EDIT: Perhaps, it was a problem with Windows. The problem has gone after reinstalling it.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is as helpful as going to the doctor and saying "it hurts, fix it". Please provide stack traces, the commands you've entered, versions etc.

Comment: Perhaps, it was a problem with windows. I reinstalled Windows yesterday and now the problem has gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem almost certainly is that `preact-cli` was not on your PATH - a list of programs that are globally accessible.

For what it's worth, we don't recommend installing globally. The site may still say that but the repository correctly recommends using `npx` instead.

Comment: Thank you @rschristian for your answer. But i can't test your answer now. As I said in the comment that the problem has gone after reinstalling windows. I should have edited the question. Still thank you.